# Apache não reconhece diretório virtual

Tags: php, apache

Tem um domínio que fizemos as entradas no nosso DNS apontando para nosso servidor Linux onde temos Apache/MySql/PHP/Wordpress.

Criei a pasta do Wordpress em /var/www com o nome **meu-site.com.br**.

**Criei o banco de dados e usuários.**

**Restaurei o backup do bd.**

**Subi o site do wrodpress para a pasta /var/www.**

No arquivo .htaccess tem:

> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule
>   ^index.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

**Acertei a configuração para bd, usuário e senha no arquivo wp-config.php.**

**Fiz a configuração em /etc/apache2/sites-available, onde criei um arquivo de configuração meu-site.com.br**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Ativei o site em /etc/apache2/sites-enabled via sudo a2ensite.**

O problema é que ao tentar acessar o site via browser é redirecionado para outro domínio meu no mesmo servidor que não tem nada a ver.

O domínio exibido existe e esta no meu servidor, mas não tem nada a ver com o domínio que informei no browser.

Tenho vários sites que fiz a configuração e funciona, mas este não quer funcionar.

Comment: Seria importante, você [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/261795/edit) a pergunta e colocar as configurações que fez! Principalmente se o site conter o arquivo `.htaccess`. Assim como está é impossível identificar aonde está o erro!

Comment: @wmsouza agradeço a ajuda. Não sou especialista no assunto, mas já tinha publicado outros sites e nunca tive problemas. O que acontece é como se o domínio que estou tentando acessar não existisse no meu servidor. Eu acesso  meu-site.com.br e retorna outro-site.com.br. Agora se eu trocar a configuração do outro-site.com.br e apontar para a pasta do meu-site.com.br funciona.

Comment: Como é essa estrutura sua, quantos sites tem no mesmo servidor?

Comment: @MagicHat tenho um 10 sites. Todos wordpress e funciona. São sites com acesso na rede interna e externa. O antigos funcionam, somente os dois novos que vão sempre para o site errado.

Comment: Não deveria haver uma tag `<VirtualHost>`?

Comment: @MagicHat  tem sim, não sei pq não tava aparecendo. Mas coloquei uma imagem. Fiz o processo que sempre faço, contudo os dois novos sites não são carregados. Os outros todos funcionam.

Comment: Como está o `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: @MagicHat normalmente não utilizo o  '/etc/hosts'. Só crio o arq de configuração '/etc/apache2/sites-available' e depois criava o vínculo em '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'. E funcionava. E melhor usar o host?